# concrete maths, sums. The upper limit does not match the definite sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

In this image [image: The equation I have problem with]

Why is the first term in right side of the equation $a_n b_n$ and not $a_{n-1} b_{n-1}$. Since $k$'s max value is n-1 and not n, as per the described limits on k.

For reference, 2.56 is[image]

Comment: Try writing out the sum with, say, n=2.

Comment: oh yes it makes sense. That definitely helped. It makes sense. the LHS has a $a_{k+1}$ term and which causes $a_{n+1} b_n$ to appear, and $a_{n+1} b_{n+1}$ gets cancelled with one of the terms produced in the second summation of RHS.

My main query lies with the fact that when we apply the upper and lowers limits on 2.56 (to convert it from an indefinite sum to a definite sum), I thought that the $u v$ will have the upper limit of $n$ instead of $n+1$. Like if you directly use the formula. I cant seem to exactly convey my question. I'll try to re-write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the maximal value for $k$ is $n-1$ but you have an index $k+1$. So plug in $n-1$ for $k$ and you obtain $k+1=n-1+1=n$.